# What is the idea behind creation of a compound word - 处决?

Tags: etymology

I wonder what the idea (etymology) is behind formation of this word 处决.

Is it something like this:

*to place + to decide = to decide a place for the convict?*

Comment: note one of the meanings of 处,

bkrs: 处: 4) punish; sentence, e.g.惩处,  
把他处以死刑

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> '[处](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/779/)' in '处决' means "to sentence/ to put to"

The basic meaning of the verb '**处**' is '**to place**', and '**to sentence**' is an extended meaning.

- "**处**以極刑" = "**to place** someone in the situation of receive capital punishment"= "**to sentence** someone to capital punishment"

> '[决](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/878/)' in '处决' means "to execute"

The basic meaning of the verb '**决**' is '**to determine**' and '**to execute**' is an extended meaning.

- to determine-->  to put an end to--> to put to death

> **[处决](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/9137/)** as a compound word is a verb means 1.**to decide a matter** 2. **to execute/ to put to death**

Examples:

- 公司上下事情由他全權**處決**-  He alone **decides matters** on all affairs of the company
- **處決**某人 - **Execute** someone.

Comment: So 處決 is always about "killing", it's not about "executing programm", right?

Comment: 處決 someone always mean to put someone to death;  executing program is 執行程序 in Chinese

Comment: it refers to the action/procedure to kill someone, not criminal charge/accusation, can be done by police or criminal.

Comment: @coobit for exmaple, **the criminal has been _executed_**, may be translated to **罪犯已被 _处决_ / _处死_ / _枪决_** etc, the literal meaning is 罪犯已被执行(死刑), the word 死刑 is not neccesary in English.

Comment: @coobit You may understand it in Chinese thoughts: **执行**死刑 (**execute** the death sentence) is more idiomatic than **处决**罪犯 (**execute** the criminal), also, **执行**程序 (**execute** a programm) is similar. The word 执行 sometimes likes **perform** or **run** in English.